# feathersjs: ignore url query-parameter in database-query

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

is there a way to ignore URL-Query-parameters in database-querys?

Background:

I have a GET/Find-REST-Endpoint `/parts` and want to specifiy something like `/parts?format=type1` to receive the data in a specific format.

I would do the formatting in the `after hook` in the `parts service`. But throws an error saying the column `"parts.format" is not specified`.

So how to ignore certain url query parameters for the database, but use them in an `after hook logic`?

Comment: I'm still pretty new to feathers, but you might be able to store that variable in the context in an earlier hook, then remove it from whatever gets passed into the hook throwing that error.  At your exit hook, it should still be in the context where you stored it.

Comment: Good suggestion, working for me!

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript object destructuring and spread in a [Feathers hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html) can be quite useful here:

```
async context => {
  const { query: { format, ...query } } = context.params;

  context.params = {
    ...context.params,
    query,
    format
  }

  return context;
}
```

This will remove `format` from the `query` and set `params.format` instead. Another advantage is that no original objects will be modified.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `delete` function of javascript ?

This hook extracts query params and apply them to `context.params`

```
function extractQueryParams(...fields){
  return context => {
    fields.forEach(field => {
      context.params[field] = context.params.query[field]
      delete context.params.query[field]
    })

    return context
  }
}

// can be used like this 
before: {
    all: [extractQueryParams('delivery')],
}
```